# CakePHP ErrorHandler error

Tags: php, cakephp

I changue the cakePhp aplication to other server, and when I open the aplication in a browser set me a 500 error.

This in the log file

```
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.163058 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.163643 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.164255 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  set_error_handler() expects the argument (ErrorHandler::handleError) to be a valid callback in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 441
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.165066 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.165575 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.168452 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  set_exception_handler() expects the argument (ErrorHandler::handleException) to be a valid callback in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 444
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.169506 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.169994 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.170466 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CakeLog' not found in /var/www/html/scrum/app/Config/bootstrap.php on line 184
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.171738 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.172466 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sun Feb 14 13:21:03.172844 2016] [:error] [pid 29544] [client 201.242.221.40:28717] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
```

The actual folder is scrum, and the aplication call a libraries in a folder orangescrum.

Any idea where I can change the name of folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you change the login and password to connect to your database too ?, if not try to do that it will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can find the file in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php

the message tell we , the file is miss

---

failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/scrum/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545

Answer (score 0):

Check the `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` constant in your `app/webroot/index.php` (and `test.php`) file, when baking it may get overriden with a hardcoded, environment specific path.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8.0/app/webroot/index.php#L60**