# No such file or directory error CakePHP

Tags: php, docker, cakephp

I inherited a CakePHP project and I am having issues getting the project running. I am running into these errors

```
[Fri Feb 02 00:05:35.920569 2018] [:error] [pid 536] [client 172.18.0.1:38124] PHP Warning:  include(/home/tablereserv/web/tablereserv.com/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /src/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 547
[Fri Feb 02 00:05:35.920638 2018] [:error] [pid 536] [client 172.18.0.1:38124] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/tablereserv/web/tablereserv.com/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /src/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 547
[Fri Feb 02 00:05:35.920658 2018] [:error] [pid 536] [client 172.18.0.1:38124] PHP Warning:  set_error_handler() expects the argument (ErrorHandler::handleError) to be a valid callback in /src/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 443
```

The file path that is trying to be included, `/home/tablereserv/web/tablereserv.com/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php` does exist and the actual path to that file is `/src/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php`

I have found some similar questions like the ones below, but none of the answers were particularly helpful

[CakePHP ErrorHandler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395085/cakephp-errorhandler-error)
[PHP Warning: include(/var/www/html/....../lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php): failed to open stream Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619750/php-warning-include-var-www-html-lib-cake-error-errorhandler-php-fail)

When I print out the CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH variable, I get the correct path but something is obviously going wrong somewhere and I can’t seem to find it.

I also think I should mention that I set up a docker container to run the project in, I’m not sure if that could have an impact on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `/public_html` != `/src`

Comment: changing it from /src to /public_html still gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I found out that file mappings are stored in a file with a name similar to `appname_cake_core_file_map`. Once I deleted the cache file and ran the request again, a new mapping was generated with the correct path.